# VBA Publishing temporary HTML file using RangetoHTML, run time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

I am running into a run time error 1004 when I'm using the following code. My Code used to work in the beginning. Now I don't know why it stopped working. When the debug the error it shows that the following lines cause the error:

```
    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With
```

This is my complete Code. It's supposed the automatically create an msg-file in outlook:

```
Sub EmailSenden()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sTemplate As String
    Dim Folder As String
    Dim Filename As String

    Set rng = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:D5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    'sTemplate = Sheets("E-Mail Text").Shapes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
    
    sTemplate = Worksheets("E-Mail Text").Cells(2, 1).Value
    
    Folder = Worksheets("ARF File Path").Cells(1, 2).Value
    If Left$(Folder, 1) <> "\" Then Folder = Folder & "\"

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    sHTML2 = Replace(sTemplate, "[@Time]", Format(Now, "hh:mm") & " Uhr")
    sHTML2 = Replace(sHTML2, "[@SamplesToWhichTargetLab]", Worksheets("E-Mail Text").Cells(3, 1).Value)
    sHTML2 = Replace(sHTML2, Chr(10), "<br>")
    sHTML2 = Replace(sHTML2, "[@SampleTable]", RangetoHTML(rng))

        
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    With OutMail
        .To = Worksheets("To").Cells(1, 2).Value
        .CC = Worksheets("CC").Cells(1, 2).Value
        .Subject = "Daily Carrier " & Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")
        .HTMLBody = sHTML2
        .Display

        Filename = Dir$(Folder & "*")

        Do Until Filename = vbNullString

            Call .Attachments.Add(Folder & Filename)

            Filename = Dir$

        Loop
    End With

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
    ' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
        Filename:=TempFile, _
        Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
        Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
        HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
    
    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
        "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: What error message do you get? Is the filename correct (separator _/_ looks strange to me)?

Comment: Hi Shrotter, it's a normal Runtime Error 1004 saying 'Application-defined or Object-defined error'.

Comment: As indicate in previous comment. Separator \ not /. `TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to save a temporarily file on the disk. You can copy the required range in Excel and using the Word object model (see the [WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property) you can paste the copied data into the message body preserving the markup.

---

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately. For example:

```
     Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
       'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
       Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
       'Create e-mail item 
       Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
       With objMail 
        'Set body format to HTML 
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
        .Display 
       End With 
     End Sub
```

3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi Eugene, do you maybe have an concrete example for me how to solve this problem?